# how to select distinct or union in 3 tables? avoid data repetition

Tags: php

my code is like this, im stuck for hours :(, in the query below, the data display are ok but I want to avoid display of repetition data value,I want to distinct firstname and lastname from user and the branch_name from branch table.

```
select  *
from `user`,`appointment`,`branch`
where user.user_id = appointment.branch_id
   and branch.branch_id = appointment.branch_id
```

I want to distinct the firstname and lastname from user and also distinct branch_name from branch? i made it like this,

```
select  distinct user.firstname, user.lastname
from user
inner join appointment on appointment.user_id = user.user_id
inner join branch on branch.branch_id
```

what should I do? the query is ok but does not display the branch_name because I still have to distinct it also, so I did it like this,

```
select  distinct user.firstname, user.lastname
from user and branch.branch_name from branch
inner join appointment on appointment.user_id = user.user_id
    and branch.branch_id = appointment.branch_id
```

please help me, thank you

Comment: `distinct` applies to the ENTIRE fieldset you're selecting. it's basically `select distinct(field1, field2, ...., fieldN)`, and not `select distinct(field1), field2, ...., fieldN`.

Comment: in my query, how should i do it?

Comment: `group by lastname, firstname`?

Comment: by lastname and firstname and branch_name from branch_id?

Comment: this code worked for me, thanks for the suggestion, justy try every query you might think will work,   $actlog_table = mysql_query("select  distinct firstname,lastname,branch_name from user join branch  join appointment on (user.user_id = appointment.user_id) and (branch.branch_id = appointment.branch_id)") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: ur answer is already correct